# Mail Merging Irish Fada's

Tags: c#, character-encoding, mailmerge, mojibake

I have a text file that I am using as a data source for a Mail Merge template.  The Irish Fada characters (á, Á, ó, Ó, ú, Ú, í, Í, é, É) are being converted to gibberish in the output file.

The code I have is as follows:

```
var path  = "c:\template.docx";
var _dataSourcePath = "c:\source.txt";

_wrdDoc = _wrdApp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: true,OpenAndRepair: true);

wrdMailMerge.OpenDataSource(_dataSourcePath, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oMissing,
                                                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                        ref oTrue, ref oMissing);

_wrdDoc.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = true;


wrdMailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = startingRecord;
wrdMailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = endingRecord;

_wrdApp.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = false;
_wrdApp.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = false;

_wrdApp.Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections = false;
_wrdApp.Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = false;
_wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = false;
_wrdDoc.ShowSpellingErrors = false;
_wrdDoc.ShowGrammaticalErrors = false;


_wrdDoc.SpellingChecked = true;
_wrdDoc.GrammarChecked = true;
// Perform mail merge.
try
{
    WriteError("Merge Ready to execute");
    wrdMailMerge.Destination = WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
    wrdMailMerge.Execute(ref _oFalse);
    WriteError("Merge Executed.");

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    WriteError(ex.StackTrace);
    throw new Exception("There was a problem Merging the document");
    CleanUp();
    return;
}
```

I have tried various encoding options during the `.OpenDataSource`, but none seem to work.  What do I need to change?